# How to delete only recode from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table in my database

```
              Id        Name
    -------------------------
      1        1          a
      2        1          a
      3        1          a
      4        2          b
      5        2          b
      6        2          b
```

This my database table it's has 6 rows and 2 columns Id and Name

In this table field `Id` is not a primary key and i want to delete 2 number row from my by `id` field table

After Delete 2 row of table i want output like this

```
               Id        Name
    -------------------------
      1        1          a
      3        1          a
      4        2          b
      5        2          b
      6        2          b
```

Is it possible?

Comment: your id column should be unique numbers. It would be best if you maybe add a uniqueid column to this table

Comment: I want just know Is it possible to delete row from table

Comment: Your requirement is not clear could you pls explain with example. As your expected output from your table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657754/how-can-i-delete-or-select-a-row-from-a-table-that-has-a-specific-row-number

Answer (score 4):

Your ID should be unique but here is the sql to delete all IDs that are 2.

```
Delete FROM table WHERE table.Id=2;
```

Replace 'table' with your table name.

**Edit:**
It appears like you want to delete the second result.  I don't know why but here is the sql:

```
with rn AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
  FROM table  
)
DELETE
FROM rn
WHERE rn = 2
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the OP wants to delete duplicates not where the `id = 2`

Comment: You are asking how to delete the second row you listed in your table?

Comment: can you explain put `rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))` in query

Answer (score 2):

There must be some criteria in a table by which you could identify its rows. That is the primary key. How do know that the order of the rows stays the same? Your table is not even sortable, I mean you can't be sure that the same SELECT statement returns rows in the same order.

That's why I'd answer that you CAN'T delete only and exactly record number two, cause you have no order in your table. And one SELECT would result in different rows on the 2nd position.

If the Id field must have such values, probably you could add a surrogate primary key.